# ValueError: need covariance of parameters for computing (unnormalized) covariances

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm currently doing a project in machine learning. My objective is to use the following dataset to train (and test) a classification algorithm by means of multinomial logistic regression in Python: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine. I'm using Google Colab, since it's a group project.

Since I would like a nice summary of the regression results, I prefer to use the package *stadsmodels* over *skicit-learn*. However, when I try the print the summary, I get the following error: *ValueError: need covariance of parameters for computing (unnormalized) covariances*

Unfortunately, I can't upload any images due to lack of reputation. I've looked all over the internet, but I couldn't find any solution. Any help would be highly appreciated!

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm

from urllib.request import urlretrieve

#Import dataset
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data'

urlretrieve(url, 'wine.csv')

wine = pd.read_csv('wine.csv', header = None)
wine.columns = ['Wine', 'Alcohol', 'Malic acid', 'Ash', 'Alcalinity of ash', 'Magnesium', 'Total phenols', 'Flavanoids', 'Nonflavanoid phenols', 'Proanthocyanins', 'Color intensity', 'Hue', 'OD280/OD315 of diluted wines', 'Proline']

print(wine)

#Normalizing the data
X = wine.drop(['Wine'], axis=1) 
y = wine['Wine']

X_norm = sk.preprocessing.normalize(X.transpose()).transpose()
X_norm = pd.DataFrame(X_norm)
X_norm.columns = ['Alcohol', 'Malic acid', 'Ash', 'Alcalinity of ash', 'Magnesium', 'Total phenols', 'Flavanoids', 'Nonflavanoid phenols', 'Proanthocyanins', 'Color intensity', 'Hue', 'OD280/OD315 of diluted wines', 'Proline']

#Partitiong the dataset into a training- and test set

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sk.model_selection.train_test_split(X_norm, y, test_size = 0.30, random_state = 0)

#Printing the coefficients by statsmodels
model_sm = sm.MNLogit(y_train, X_train).fit(method = 'bfgs', maxiter = 1000, full_output = True, disp = True)
print(model_sm.summary())
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This means most likely that the X_train is singular and hessian inversion failed. Did you get a warning message during statsmodels `fit`?

Comment: Actually I’m using the BFGS method, which doesn’t invert the Hessian. I didn’t get any warning message using fit, but when I delete all attributed of fit, I do get a summary, but with all NaN values for all coefficients, standard errors etc.

Comment: what do you mean "when I delete all attributed of fit"? You don't see a delete in your code.  If you remove model and results attributes, then summary cannot be computed anymore, unless they are already cached.

Comment: I mean when the line ```model_sm = sm.MNLogit(y_train, X_train).fit(method = 'bfgs', maxiter = 1000, full_output = True, disp = True)``` reads ```model_sm = sm.MNLogit(y_train, X_train).fit()```

Comment: Even if optimizers like bfgs do not need the hessian, the hessian is computed in fit to get inferential statistics, standard errors and cov_params. If the hessian is not invertible, then those inferential statistics will not by available in summary (except as nans)

Comment: That clears things up! Thanks. How should I fix this?